# meu virtual device no android studio não abre meu aplicativo

Tags: android, android-studio, emulador

Eu estava criando um aplicativo, e logo após adicionar strings a alguns textviews eu tentei fazer um teste, selecionei meu virtual device, porem, quando o aparelho iniciou uma tela branca com o símbolo da google e uma barra de carregamento apareceram,como de praxe, porém o carregamento nunca acaba, o android studio me informou 2 problemas, acredito que o primeiro seja o responsável por isso:
1-emulator unable to open app... permission denied.
2-null value in entry,incremental folder=null...
gostaria de saber o que eu faço para resolver o problema

Answer (score 0):

Remova a pasta .gradle e tente de novo.

Fontes:

https://discuss.gradle.org/t/null-value-in-entry-dependencycachedir-null/19191

https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-resolve-Error-null-value-in-entry-otherFileOutputs-null-Information-BUILD-FAILED-During-Gradle-build-in-Android-Studio-2-3-1

Answer (score 0):

1. Abra o Android Studio
2. Configure -> AVD Manager
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
3. Escolha o device que quer utilizar -> Wipe Data
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

4) Tente novamente abrir o device